# How to decide what items are inside a form-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Started learning Twitter Bootstrap a couple days ago and in form-design they use form-group  but from some examples I have seen for example each label and its text box is inside one `form-grou`p and from some other examples I have seen they put multiple labels and their text boxes in one `form-group`.
So my question is what makes them know and decide which way to wrap in form-group?

Comment: Can You show examples of what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing. - [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example)

It just adds a bottom margin to help space out your controls.  I find that in most cases you would want to use them.  The only time I can think of that you might consider not using them is if the form you're styling requires a lot of custom positioning or spacing.